# Let OS X ScreenSharing accept incoming connections only from a list of trusted IPs

Tags: security, mac-osx, ip, whitelist, screen-sharing

As a security measure, is it possible to set up screen sharing on a remote Mac to accept connections only from a given list of IP addresses?

(*Of course I could set up a firewall to allow traffic on VNC specific ports only from/to trusted IPs but I was looking for a easier solution (I don't have a firewall in front of that Mac yet and I'd prefer not to mess with OS X builtin software firewall*)

Answer (score 1):

There are two mechanisms that accomplish this. One you've said you don't have presently and one you 'don't want to mess with'. You will have a difficult time accomplishing your goal given those constraints.